# C++: Creating a "cost"/"distance" matrix from a vector of strings

Tags: c++, string, vector, multidimensional-array

I have been working on this problem for a few days and was hoping for some guidance.

Let's say I have a string vector, 'myVec,' and it has been defined such that:

(Please note, these are just the values "inside" the vector, I used the push_back function to define myVec to be as follows):

```
myVec[0] = X Y 2 //There is a distance of 2 units between 'X' and 'Y'
myVec[1] = X Zebra 9 //There is a distance of 9 units between 'X' and 'Zebra'
myVec[2] = Y Zebra 3 //There is a distance of 3 units between 'Y' and 'Zebra'
```

I have also been able to save these 'locations' (X, Y and Zebra) in a string vector called 'routers', such that:

```
routers[0] = X
routers[1] = Y
routers[2] = Zebra
```

I would like to create a "cost" matrix based upon 'myVec,' in the form:

```
0 2 9
2 0 3
9 3 0
```

Each row and column is representative of the locations, 'X', 'Y', and 'Zebra'. In the first row, it says: It takes 0 units for 'X' to get to 'X', it takes 2 units for 'X' to get to Y', and it takes 9 units for 'X' to get to 'Zebra'. etc. The next row is the same relative to location 'Y', and the last row is the same relative to location 'Zebra'

My first step to create the cost matrix has been to retrieve the distance values (in this case: 2, 9 and 3)

I have created a bit of code so that I can see the distance values from 'myVec' as follows:

```
for (int i = 0; i <myVec.size(); i++)
{
    
    string s = myVec.at(i); 


    for (int j = 0; j <s.length(); j++) //going through chars of string in 'myVec' vec
    {

        if (isdigit(s[j])) //Going through myVec vector, and checking the numerical distance value
        {
            int dist = s[j] - '0'; //Converting the char to int
            cout<<dist<<endl;
        }
    }
        



}
```

The above code prints the numerical values of myVec - 2 9 and 3. However, this is where I have been stuck, as I am struggling to code how/where these distance values should be saved. The distance "2" is the distance between location 'X' and 'Y', so in a cost matrix it should be stored in locations [0][1] and [1][0]. Except, I am really struggling to figure out how I can implement this in code.I have thought about using comparisons by using the .at() function to loop through myVec, and comparing them to the locations saved in the 'routers' vector, but this kind of strategy falls when considering location 'Zebra', which is not a char, but a string...

I would really appreciate some thoughts!
Thank you.

Comment: `myVec[0] = X Y 2 ` is not C++. Please create a proper [mre]

Comment: Hello! Sorry I just edited my question. I did use push_back() to define my vectors, but I just indexed the vector to be able to communicate the values held at those vector positions.

Comment: The index is not the problem. The problem is that we don't know that the type of the vector is, we don't know what `X Zebra 9` is because it's not valid C++ code. And we can't guess because that would waste both our time. Please create a [mre].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start by converting your `myVec` to some usable struct like

```
struct edge
{
    std::string from;
    std::string to;
    int dist;
};
```

Then create a mapping from the string location names to indices. Eg first storing all possible locations in a `std::set` and then creating a `std::map<std::string, int> l2i` with that.

Create a 2d array and store all known distances. `distances[i][i] = 0;`, `distances[l2i[from]][l2i[to]] = dist;`.

Finally use https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floyd%E2%80%93Warshall_algorithm to compute APSP and generate your matrix.

Also use `std::stoi` to convert from string to int. Not your subtraction method. Since that only works for single digit distances.

Edit:
It only takes 5 units to get from X to Zebra. X -(2)> Y -(3)> Zerbra. If you just want your matrix without APSP you can also do
`distances[l2i[from]][l2i[to]] = dist;distances[l2i[to]][l2i[from]] = dist;`